# HTML Input Inside Table Default Value

Tags: html

I am creating a site creator (yeah site-ception) so anyways I have a table and each row consists of one cell of the item, the next cell the **input** for setting the item's value, and the third cell any info. But no matter what I do, **only** the **first** input in the table will **not** show its default value I gave it. Here is the code:

```html
    <p class='big'>Text</p>
        <table>
         <tr><td><p>Color</p></td><td><input type="text" value="black" /></td><td class='info'><p>Either word or hexadecimal</p></td></tr>
         <tr><td><p>Font-Family</p></td><td><input type="text" value="Verdana" /></td><td class='info'><p>Has case-sensitivity</p></td></tr>
        </table>
        <p class='big'>Divisions</p>
        <table>
         <tr><td><p>Background-Color</p></td><td><input type="text" value="white" /></td><td class='info'><p>The color in the back layer</p></td></tr>
         <tr><td><p>Border-Color</p></td><td><input type="text" value="black" /></td><td class='info'><p>The color of the bordering line</p></td></tr>
         <tr><td><p>Border-Width</p></td><td><input type="text" value="2px" /></td><td class='info'><p>In px or em units</p></td></tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Well, I don't seem to get the same result as you since it says "black" when I run the code.  Maybe add any Javascript that could be altering the table?

Comment: I do have javascript but it's very short and entirely unrelated to the table.

Comment: So, just to be clear, you are NOT seeing any text appear inside the first input field (next to Color), but all the other input fields display a default value on page load (like, Verdana, white, black and 2px)?  PS - can you post any CSS you might be using?